# Xpath to get element value

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to use xpath to get the value of `Odometer` out of my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CWEAI xmlns="http://www.carrierweb.com/Schema/CWEAI_schema_1.0/cwReturnTruckCanbusHistory">

  <cwReturnTruckCanbusHistory>
    <ID>549094411</ID>
    <CWVehicleID>109755</CWVehicleID>
    <Odometer>1374031</Odometer>
    <Fuel>452800</Fuel>
    <FuelLevel>1000</FuelLevel>

  </cwReturnTruckCanbusHistory>
</CWEAI>
```

I have tried about anything but I can not get a working xpath:

```
CWEAI/cwReturnTruckCanbusHistory/Odometer

CWEAI/cwReturnTruckCanbusHistory/Odometer/text

CWEAI[@xmlns="http://www.carrierweb.com/Schema/CWEAI_schema_1.0/cwReturnTruckCanbusHistory"]/cwReturnTruckCanbusHistory/Odometer
```

Comment: In what context do you need to to do this? What programming language etc?

Comment: Language is not defined in the file, cant see anything of lang= .. Default language is english maybe?

Comment: I assumed that you actually need to do something more than just getting a value from an online XPath test tool. What are you using the `Odometer` value for?

Comment: Oh yes, my database is copying the value of the xpath and saving it to a database. The problem is that my database can not find a value because my xpath is incorrect. Hopefully u can help me haha!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`text` is Xpath function, so use it in the proper way

```
/CWEAI/cwReturnTruckCanbusHistory/Odometer/text()
```

It results in `Text='1374031'`

Working in php:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true); 
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('c', current($ns));

$target = $xml->xpath('//c:CWEAI//c:cwReturnTruckCanbusHistory/c:Odometer/text()');
echo $target[0];
```

**[demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/791570)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reaction, I have just added the xmlns what was in the orginal file. It seems to run fine without it and errors when I add that, do you know how I can fix it with the xmlns??

Comment: You should register that namespace before use xpath. It is done in different  ways in different languages

Comment: Language is not defined in the file, is there a default language selected? If so, how do i get my xpath in that default language?